# MS Graph SDK .NET get all items from a SharePoint library, even if checked out

Tags: c#, .net, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I try to get all items from a SharePoint library, regardless of its status (checkin/out). Why does my code don't get the checked out items/documents

```
graphClient.Sites["SITEID"].Lists["LISTID"].Items.Request().Expand("createdByUser,fields,driveItem").GetAsync().Result;
```

Edit:

- Versioning is on
- If entry is first version and checked out, it will not be displayed
- If there are several versions, the versions before last is displayed (level = published)

Answer (score 2):

`driveItem` resource has `publication` property which provides information about the published or checked-out state of an item, in locations that support such actions.

This property is not returned by default.

You have to add `$select` statement to `driveItem` in `Expand` method.

```
graphClient.Sites["SITEID"]
    .Lists["LISTID"]
    .Items
    .Request()
    .Expand("createdByUser,fields,driveItem($select=publication)")
    .GetAsync().Result;
```

`PublicationFacet` has property `level` which describes the state of publication for document. Either `published` or `checkout`.

Resources:

[driveItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/driveitem?view=graph-rest-1.0)

[publicationFacet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/publicationfacet?view=graph-rest-1.0)

Comment: Thank you for your help, this really helps me further to understand the SDK. Unfortunately, it doesn't solve my problem that files that have been checked out are not displayed. But I think it is because the versioning is on. Because files that only have one version and are checked out are not displayed, but as soon as they have more than one version, the version before last is always displayed. Of course, the level is always shown as "published"....